# How to embed a script so that it acts as a widget?

Tags: javascript

I have some information in my website which I need to include in my friends website but if I got through script inclusion I will fell into cross domain problem. Currently my website is based on ajax. Any idea or reference to achieve this?

Any help will be great!

Thanks,
Karthik

Comment: Have you tried saving your JavaScript in a separate file and sending it to your friend so he can store it on his web server and have his pages load it as per usual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ajax you can use something called [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

jquery makes it easy - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: I heard about this stuff but can't it be accomplished through JSON?@experimentX:I want to embed an external html file and based on the user's website I have to send a request to my server and generate the contents in host's website.Any way thanks for all your support

Comment: you can't do a cross site get request with json, jsonp is just json wrapped with a function eg load_data({value: 123});

Comment: I know that so the best way is to do using jsonP and I agree with that.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could either put it in an iframe if it is a stand alone widget, or use flash as a proxy to do the ajax and create a proper cross domain policy for the flash component.